# SSH with LDAP authentication (ActiveDirectory) and ssh keys stored in AD

Tags: ssh, authentication, ldap

*Environment :* Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04 Servers, Active Directory on Windows Server 2016, Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04 clients. Ubuntu servers and clients are not on the domain.

Hello everyone,

I'm a little lost with all ways to achieve ldap authentication for ssh. But I can't find a suitable one for me.

My wish : I wan't to connect to my servers by login in with "sAMAccount@serverIP", my SSH keys are stored in my AD (new field added as odiSSHPubKeys).
My server well communicate with my AD (ldapsearch query). I achieved that by updating my sshdconfig :

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/auth
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

**/usr/bin/auth**

```
#!/bin/bash

cn=$1
server=ldap.myad.net #Put your server IP
basedn=dc=mydomain,dc=net #Put your basedn
port=389
bindUser=myBindUser
bindPass=myBindUserPassword
#cn=mathieu

ldapsearch -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -x -h $server -p $port -b $basedn -D $bindUser -w $bindPass -s sub "(sAMAccountName=$cn)" | sed -n 's/^[ \t]*odiSSHPubKeys:[ \t]*\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

When I connect to mathieu@192.168.0.231, I'm kicked by preauth

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Apr 18 11:56:26 MLL-HV-UBU-16 sshd[9103]: Invalid user mathieu from 192.168.0.114
Apr 18 11:56:26 MLL-HV-UBU-16 sshd[9103]: input_userauth_request: invalid user mathieu [preauth]
Apr 18 11:56:26 MLL-HV-UBU-16 sshd[9103]: Connection closed by 192.168.0.114 port 50152 [preauth]
```

So my problem is that "mathieu" doesn't exist as user on my Ubuntu server. 
I try to force my cn in my /usr/bin/auth and log with root account (root@192.168.0.231) and it works, so my /usr/bin/auth id good.

How can I disable preauth check to let ldap works ?

PS : I don't want a login/password authentication (for this solution, there is a lot of tutos, but not many for ssh keys or old ones).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not even a clue ?
I'll have to do login/password authentication and add my servers in domain in that case :(

Comment: Suggest using for TLS based ldap port for this. iirc 389 ain't.

Comment: @FlorianHeigl 389 is, if you use STARTTLS.

Comment: @matll42 You could also just use GSSAPI auth. It uses Kerberos to do passwordless auth and it "just works".

Answer (score 6):

Best option here is to use sssd for this purpose. I use the AltSecurityIdentities to store the keys and join the servers to the domain using realmd.

Once domain joined, add the following to the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file under the [domain/] section:

```
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_use_tokengroups = True
```

and under the [sssd] section add:

```
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh
```

Then to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config add:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

Restart both services, and you should be able to login using your AD username and the password stored in the AltSecurityIdentities extended attribute in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I worked on a Go tool that syncs SSH keys to your servers, based on Github/Gitlab groups memberships.

Check it out !
==> http://github.com/samber/sync-ssh-keys

This avoids some hacks with LDAP :-(

Comment: As I also use Gitlab and all my SSH users are Gitlab users, I'll take a look at this alternative. Thanks

Comment: Kudos for ingenuity, but *this* actually is the hackish way of doing things.  Modifying LDAP appropriately is the way to go ...